# What does this count?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> What does this count?
>   ${w\choose3} \cdot {m\choose2} + {w\choose4} \cdot m + {w\choose5} $
>
> (a) The number of ways to choose $5$ people out of a group consisting of $w$ women and $m$ men, where at most $3$ women can be chosen.
>
> (b)The number of ways to choose $5$ people out of a group consisting of $w$ women and $m$
>   men, where at most $3$ men can be chosen.
>
> **(c) The number of ways to choose $5$ people out of a group consisting of $w$ women and $m$ men, where at least $3$ women must be chosen.**
>
> (d) The number of ways to choose $5$ people out of a group consisting of $w$ women and $m$ men, where at least $3$ men must be chosen

Not too sure why its **(c)**, can someone explain? I thought it was (b) because of the ${m\choose2}$ and $m$ parts. Why is it only $5$ people as well?

Comment: How many ways are there to choose three women and two men?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**And** means product, here are all the case:

- $3$ Women **and** $2$ Men: $\displaystyle {w \choose 3}{m \choose 2}$
- $4$ Women **and** $1$ Man: $\displaystyle {w \choose 4}{m \choose 1}$
- $5$ Women: $\displaystyle {w \choose 5}{m\choose 0}$

where $\displaystyle {m \choose 1}=m, {m\choose 0}=1$.

> Thus the result is: $\displaystyle {w \choose 3}{m \choose 2}+{w \choose 4}m+{w \choose 5}$  and this is at most $2$ Men as you can see.

In other words:

At most $2$ men $=$ at least $3$ Women (Choice $c$) [*The Correct Answer*]

At most $3$ men $=$ at least $2$ Women (Choice $b$)